# Tests with debug do not start with Javascript Debug Terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code, nestjs

I try to run my `nest.js` tests with debug inside `Javascript Debug Terminal`, and it halts without starting the tests themselves:

```
zagrava@zagrava-Z390-D:~/workspace/kpi-tool/backend$ yarn run test:debug:new
Debugger attached.
yarn run v1.22.18
$ node --inspect-brk -r tsconfig-paths/register -r ts-node/register node_modules/.bin/jest --watch  --runInBand
```

The script itself looks like this:

```
    "test:debug:new": "node --inspect-brk -r tsconfig-paths/register -r ts-node/register node_modules/.bin/jest --watch  --runInBand",
```

Is there a way to make it run?

Answer (score 0):

Making the debugger works highly depends on the setup of your project. Can you share a public repository containing a reproduction of your problem?

In any case, I suggest you trying to use `nest debug` instead of running directly with `node` in your debug script. Maybe trying with that would help you with your problem

Comment: I have just tried it with new nestjs project. Just run app.controller.spec.ts, insert the script in my question and you will reproduce.

But, do you mean there is a way to debug my Jest tests through this `nest debug` command?

Comment: Yes, the easiest way to launch a debugger with NestJS is by using the nest debug command.